# where can i find best source to learn dynamics 365 crm model driven app development

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi

what is best source to learn dynamics 365 crm model driven app development.i'm searching the net from 3 weeks i'm unable to find so. i even tried to learn from Microsoft docs but found very old data which is very hard to understand. so please help me as i need to learn it as quickly as i can. Even in the net also i mostly ended up with results showing how to use dynamics crm application or solving errors in application development not a clear video or source content which helps in learning how to develop a model driven application in dynamics crm from scratch. Please help me to learn.

Answer (score 1):

These current links may help:

[What is Common Data Service?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/common-data-service/data-platform-intro)

[Developers: Get started with Common Data Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/get-started-cds-developers)

[Model-driven apps Developer Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/overview)

Comment: but microsoft documentation is very hard to understand. could you please let me know if you know any other sources

Comment: I believe that there are a lot of videos on YouTube that may be helpful. There are also training courses available.